# bxslider somente texto, quando chamo o js os textos somem

Tags: javascript, jquery, slider, bxslider

Estou com um problema no bxslider, na verdade não sei se é problema ou se ele não aceita somente textos. Tenho esse código abaixo:

```html
 <ul class="bxslider row">
  <% student.qrcodes.each do |qrcode| %>
    <li class="col-xs-12 col-sm-4 col-md-4">
      <span class="aluno_<%= qrcode.program.short_name.downcase %>"><%= qrcode.code %></span>
      <small><%= "#{qrcode.program.short_name} - #{qrcode.year_reference}" %></small>
    </li>
  <% end %>
</ul>
```

Que me gera isso:

[image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]

Mas quando eu chamo o JS para ativar o slide `$('.bxslider').bxSlider();` acontece isso aqui:

[image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]

Simplesmente os "textos" somem.

Alguma ideia do que pode ser?

OBS: Editado, coloquei o código JS do `bxslider` no `jsfiddle` pq não coube no post:

https://jsfiddle.net/69krutjL/

Comment: Atualize a resposta com os códigos javascript usado e em vez de colocar o código da view programacionalmente substitua pelo código renderizado.

Comment: @FelipeAssunção  editei o post colocando um link para o código do js do bxslider.  vlw